# php splitting a file into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array

I am needing a little help with splitting the contents of a file into a multidimensional array.

Sample of the file contents :

```
--[DEATH KNIGHT]--
--|Blood|--
--{Single}--
/* MACRO CODE FOR SINGLE TARGET */
--{MULTI}--
/* MACRO CODE FOR MULTIPLE TARGETS */
--|Frost|--
/* MACRO CODE FOR SINGLE TARGET */
--{MULTI}--
/* MACRO CODE FOR MULTIPLE TARGETS */
--{Single}--
--[DRUID]--
--|Guardian|--
--{Single}--
/* MACRO CODE FOR SINGLE TARGET */
--{Multi}--
/* MACRO CODE FOR MULTIPLE TARGETS */
```

I need to read this file and split it into an array with the following structure :

```
array(
  'DEATHKNIGHT' => array(
    'Blood' => array(
      'Single' = 'Single Target Macro Code',
      'Multi' = 'Multiple Target Macro Code'
      ),
    'Frost' => array(
      'Single' = 'Single Target Macro Code',
      'Multi' = 'Multiple Target Macro Code'
      )
  ),
  'DRUID' => array(
    'Guardian' => array(
      'Single' = 'Single Target Macro Code',
      'Multi' = 'Multiple Target Macro Code'
      )
)
```

I am using file_get_contents() to read the contents of the file into a string. I I am using preg_match_all() to pull out my defined array keys. The following are the regex that I am using:

```
$class_regex = '/(?:-{2})(?:\[)(?:[A-Z][\w]+)(?:[\s][A-Z][\w]+)?(?:\])(?:-{2})/';
$spec_regex = '/(?:-{2})(?:\|)(?:[A-Z][\w]+)(?:[\s][A-Z][\w]+)?(?:\|)(?:-{2})/i';
$target_regex = '/(?:-{2})(?:\{)(?:[A-Z][\w]+)(?:[\s][\(][\d][\D][\)])?(?:\})(?:-{2})/i';
```

I can pull out the keys successfully, and I can seperate the file into specific elements, but I am struggling when trying to create my array. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read it line by line with `while ($line = fgets($file))` instead of reading the whole thing with `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Are those 'target' keys `Single` and `Multi` static(constant) within your file content?

Comment: Yes, 'Single' and 'Multi' are static. everything else is not. The 'Macro Code' will vary in length. Meaning that each 'macro code' will cover a different amount of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Barmar said you should go through it line by line using fgets instead of file_get_contents.

Here is an example script that does what you asked.  You'll probably want to extend it with extra validation and such.

```
<?php
$parsed = array();
$handle = fopen("source.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        if (preg_match('/^--\[((?:[A-Z][\w]+)(?:[\s][A-Z][\w]+)?)\]--$/', $line, $match)) {
            $class = $match[1];
        } elseif (preg_match('/^--\|((?:[A-Z][\w]+)(?:[\s][A-Z][\w]+)?)\|--$/', $line, $match)) {
            $spec = $match[1];
        } elseif (preg_match('/^--\{((?:[A-Z][\w]+)(?:[\s][A-Z][\w]+)?)\}--$/', $line, $match)) {
            $target = $match[1];
        } else {
            if (isset($class) && isset($spec) && isset($target)) {
                if (empty($parsed[$class])) {
                    $parsed[$class] = array();
                }
                if (empty($parsed[$class][$spec])) {
                    $parsed[$class][$spec] = array();
                }
                if (empty($parsed[$class][$spec][$target])) {
                    $parsed[$class][$spec][$target] = '';
                }
                $parsed[$class][$spec][$target] .= $line;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo print_r($parsed);
```